# How can I block all Tumblr blogs?

Tags: firefox, websites, opera, chrome-extension, adblock

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and need a foolproof way to permanently block Tumblr blogs from being accessed on my system. Browser extensions such as Blocksite  arent effective even when using 'wildcards' such as *.tumblr.com

Elsewhere, I have seen an (outdated) suggestion to block static.tumblr.com and 78.media.tumblr.com, but this no longer works against Tumblr at time of writing, i.e. even with these domains blocked, I can browse a given Tumblr blog without interruptions.

Comment: You can add `127.0.0.1 static.tumblr.com` and `127.0.0.1 78.media.tumblr.com` to the end of `/etc/hosts`, but are you sure that blocking these domains is enough?

Comment: @Yaron with the introduction of things on Tumblr since that're CDNs adn everything, just blocking those two are ineffective - note they tried blocking those with browser-level plugins and it didn't work.  What OP needs is a content proxy, something with content categories and filtration automatically.  However that'll block blogs/social networks entirely in that setup.

Comment: @Tomas Ward Indeed. Keep in mind also that I only have control on my machine (as in not on the internet router) since where I live I am bound by the contract not to bring in my own connection. Am forced to share the on-site Wi-Fi. I would like to block "Tumblr" in its entirety.